# transformToXML in php 5 doesn't work when page is loaded from old explorer

Tags: php, xslt

I'm having a very strange situation right now with the behaviour of transformToXML in PHP 5.3.

We can say that my question is what is the relation between the requesting client and the work done in the server?

I don't have any rules related to user-agent or anything similar and the transformations. The xml generated is different, but it's always valid. Also, the differences involve the detection of explorer, but not the version of the browser. I always send the most basic version of the page to explorer.

**This is the code involved (php):**

```
// var definition and initialization  
$temp['document'] = new DOMDocument();  
$xslDoc = new DOMDocument();  
$xslDoc->load( 'index.xslt' );  
$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();  
$xslt->importStylesheet( $xslDoc );  

...

// this dumps the xml document as it has been generated  
// $temp['document'] is generated above. Is valid and well formed xml  
var_dump( $temp['document'] );  

// load xml generated into DOMdocument object  
$xmlDoc->loadXML( $temp['document'] );  

// apply xsl transformation rules  
$final_doc = $xslt->transformToXML( $xmlDoc );  

// this dumps the tags writen in the xsl and the variables applied,  
// but not the transformations  
var_dump( $final_doc );  
exit( __FILE__.' '.__LINE__);  
...
```

If I request the page with any browser, including explorer 9 in normal mode, everything works fine, no errors and the page is generated. This includes any version in windows and linux, plus tested with more versions in browsershots. Well, except konqueror.

If I request  the page with explorer 6 or any modern version using compatibility view or konqueror 4.8.5, the templates don't work.

Since the process is happening in the server, I don't understand that behaviour. Why the `<xsl:template match="some_tag">` or the `<xsl:apply-templates />` are failing?

There are no error in my logs or in libxml_get_last_error() or libxml_get_errors().

Any help to understand or troubleshoot this will be really appreciated.

If more info is needed, I can try to post it, just let me know.

Bye and thanks

**xsl file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id_pagina">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="/pagina/id_pagina/@valor">
                <xsl:value-of select="/pagina/id_pagina/@valor" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>x</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$id_pagina" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <div id="Base">
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </div>

            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="cabecera">
        <div id="zona_de_cabecera"><xsl:apply-templates /></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contenido">
        <div id="zona_de_contenido" class="shadow"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="pie[*]">
        <div id="zona_de_pie"><xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/></div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="div">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="span">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="img">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Have you inspected what is sent to the browser? Also, "dosn't work" is not an error description. Please be more precise.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for the answer, yes, I have checked the output to the browser, that's what the var_dumps are there for. :)

plus the comments in the code area in my question describe the output of the var_dump

Comment: Please show us details of the XSLT, in particular I would like to see any `xsl:output` you use and whether you are outputting HTML 4 or 5 with elements being in no namespace or XHTML with elements being in a namespace. Also is the URL public? If so post it so that we can test.

Comment: no problem, I'm adding it.

As you can see, is a very simple one. Since is still not working for all the needed browsers, I haven't finished it.

Answer (score 0):

Well in the current code

```
var_dump( $temp['document'] );

// load xsl
$xsl->importStylesheet( $xslDoc );
$xslDoc->loadXML( $temp['document'] );

// this dumps object(DOMDocument)[1]
var_dump( $xmlDoc );

// apply xsl
$final_doc = $xsl->transformToXML( $xslDoc );

// this dumps the tags writen in the xsl and the variables applied, but not the
// transformations
var_dump( $final_doc );
```

as posted you first use `$xslDoc` to import the stylesheet, then you use the same variable with `$xslDoc->loadXML( $temp['document'] )` to parse some XML string, however then you dump a different variable named `$xmlDoc`, then you pass `$xslDoc` to transformToXML. That looks to me as if you want to use two different variables where `$xslDoc` should be the stylesheet and `$xmlDoc` the input to the stylesheet, but somehow your code confuses those variables and that way you don't get what you want. So if your real code is as posted then I suggest you make sure you use two distinct DOM documents, one for the stylesheet, one for the input, and you pass the input to transformToXML.

Comment: you are completely right, but unfortunately I have to say that the error you spotted is a typo when I was writing the code here, thanks for telling me and I'll update that in a moment.